# clearInterval and clearTimer not working on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I have looked over all the clearInterval/clearTimeout answers and they all say to do what I'm already doing. Still, my timeout and interval won't clear. I'm thinking maybe because it's in Wordpress? IDK, please help...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var slideshow_timer;
var slideshow_delay;

    function initSlideshow() {
  slideshow_delay = setInterval(startSlideshow, 5000);
}

function startSlideshow() {
    if(!slideshow_timer){
        clearInterval(slideshow_delay);
        slideshow_timer = setTimeout(startSlideshow, 5000);
    }
}

function stopSlideshow() {
    if(slideshow_timer){
        clearTimeout(slideshow_timer);
    }else{  
        clearInterval(slideshow_delay);
    }
}
});
```

When I console.log the variables I still get numbers.

*I stripped out a lot of additonal crap that makes the slideshow animate and broke it down to just the intervals and the timeouts.

Comment: What is the actual problem ? just that the variables do not reset ?

Answer (score 1):

Even after clearing a timer, the variable you stored its return value in will remain unchanged. It doesn't get set back to 0 or undefined, even though it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the intervals does not reset the actual variables..

It just stops the timers.

---

If you need to restart the slideshow, then you will have to manually reset the variables once you stop the timers.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var slideshow_timer;
    var slideshow_delay;

        function initSlideshow() {
      slideshow_delay = setInterval(startSlideshow, 5000);
    }

    function startSlideshow() {
        if(!slideshow_timer){
            clearInterval(slideshow_delay);
            slideshow_delay = null;
            slideshow_timer = setTimeout(startSlideshow, 5000);
        }
    }

    function stopSlideshow() {
        if(slideshow_timer){
            clearTimeout(slideshow_timer);
            slideshow_timer = null;
        }else{  
            clearInterval(slideshow_delay);
            slideshow_delay = null;
        }
    }
});
```